# Trying to convert an NOT EXIST into COUNT

Tags: sql, select, count

So I know how to do the query with using `NOT EXIST`.
But I can't seem to find the equivelent using `COUNT` instead.

Structure:

```
player(playerID: integer, playerName: string)
team(teamID: integer, teamName: string, sport: string)
plays(playerID: integer, teamID: integer)
```

The `NOT EXIST` query I came up which works:

```
SELECT distinct player.playerID, playerName
FROM player, plays
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT teamID
     FROM team
     WHERE sport='football' AND NOT EXISTS
           (SELECT teamID
           FROM plays
           WHERE team.teamID=plays.teamID AND player.playerid=plays.playerid));
```

The query finds player that plays for all football teams.
I am trying to do the same with using count. To start it off, I know that I have to count number of time the football appears under sports and then that player has to play for all the `TeamID`'s for which the sport is football. I get confused after that. Any hints?

Comment: How do you mean you want to change not exist to count? What do you want to count?

Comment: @FilipeSilva I want to be able to find all players that play for ALL football teams. I found the query with the using NOT EXIST. I want to find it using COUNT instead and still get the same results.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

What it seems like you are looking for is a query retrieving all players `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT teamID)` equal to the total number of teams (limited to `'football'`), indicating the player plays for every team.

```
SELECT
  player.playerID
  player.playerName
FROM
  player 
  INNER JOIN plays ON player.playerID = plays.playerID
  INNER JOIN team ON plays.teamID = team.teamID
WHERE team.sport = 'football'
/* A player with a count of distinct teamID equal to the total possible teams
   indicates the player plays for all teams */
GROUP BY player.playerID,  player.playerName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT plays.teamID) = (SELECT COUNT(teamID) FROM team WHERE sport='football')
```

In fact, with this form, since the `JOIN` against `team` already limits it to football teams only, you should not actually need `COUNT(DISTINCT plays.teamID)`. It ought to work with `COUNT(*)` in the `HAVING` clause, unless it is possible for a player to be listed *more than once* for the same team.

Comment: Its exactly what I want but instead of every team, I just want every every team where SPORT = 'football'

Comment: @user2632133 I think I have it now - it was not properly limited in the outer query. This should return everyone who plays for all football teams, but not _only_ football teams. In other words, if someone plays for all football plus two baseball teams, he'll be in this result.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It definately works. I am not understanding the concept of Join On even after reading it up online. Is know natural join, and outer join etc. Is there any way to do this without using "join on" specifically.

Comment: You can use implicit joins, which means comma-separated tables in the `FROM` clause like in your original. That is an old syntax, which is discouraged. The explicit `INNER JOIN` is equivalent, but the more modern preferred syntax. See also http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes sense now. I don't have enough rep to bump :( but really appreciate your help.

Comment: I just upvoted as I have 15. Thanks a lot. I posted another question, if you have a time to take a look at it. Thanks again for help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the IDs of all football teams:

   ```
   SELECT teamID
   FROM team
   WHERE sport = 'football'
   ```
2. Get the IDs of all teams a specific player has played for:

   ```
   SELECT TeamID
   FROM plays
   WHERE playerID = @playerID
   ```
3. Exclude the latter from the former

   ```
   SELECT teamID
   FROM team
   WHERE sport = 'football'

   EXCEPT

   SELECT TeamID
   FROM plays
   WHERE playerID = @playerID
   ```
4. Check if the result does not have any rows:

   ```
   NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT teamID
       FROM team
       WHERE sport = 'football'

       EXCEPT

       SELECT TeamID
       FROM plays
       WHERE playerID = @playerID
   )
   ```
5. Apply the condition to every player:

   ```
   SELECT playerID, playerName
   FROM player
   WHERE
       NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT teamID
           FROM team
           WHERE sport = 'football'

           EXCEPT

           SELECT TeamID
           FROM plays
           WHERE playerID = player.playerID
       )
   ;
   ```